# Zipping items from a list with lists from an ordered dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, items

I have a given ordered dictionary and a given list with the same length.

```
given_dict = OrderedDict([('one', ['-', '-']), ('two', ['-', '-'])])
given_list = ['a', 'b']
```

Now I would like to zip each item from the list with each list from the dictionary to get this:

```
new_dict = {'one': ['-', '-', 'a'], 'two': ['-', '-', 'b']}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a few mistakes here, first, don't use `dict` or `list` as names, they're shadow names of Python built-in functions. Also, dictionary takes like `{'key': 'value'}`, **NOT** `{'key'='value'}`. Then, Python dictionary is **UNORDERED** which means using **zip** doesn't make sense at all

Comment: @Anzel I revised my post. I hope it's clearer now. Thanks for your advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a loop ove `given_dict.items()` and add the elements of `given_list` with your values !

```
>>> given_dict = OrderedDict((j[0],j[1]+[given_list[i]]) for i,j in enumerate(given_dict.items()))
>>> given_dict
OrderedDict([('one', ['-', '-', 'a']), ('two', ['-', '-', 'b'])])
```

or if you want to give a dict , just use `dict` instead ``

```
>>> given_dict = dict((j[0],j[1]+[given_list[i]]) for i,j in enumerate(given_dict.items()))
>>> given_dict
{'two': ['-', '-', 'b'], 'one': ['-', '-', 'a']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
In [13]: given_dict = OrderedDict([('one', ['-', '-']), ('two', ['-', '-'])])

In [14]: given_list = ['a', 'b']

In [15]: {k: di + [li] for ((k, di), li) in zip(given_dict.items(), given_list)}
Out[15]: {'one': ['-', '-', 'a'], 'two': ['-', '-', 'b']}
```

Comment: upvote +1 Stick with OP requirements and purposefully using `zip`.

Comment: @NPE What do I have to change to also get an ordered dict?

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
>>> given_dict = collections.OrderedDict([('one', ['-', '-']), ('two', ['-', '-'])])
>>> given_list = ['a', 'b'] 
>>> {x[0]:x[1]+[given_list[i]] for i,x in enumerate(given_dict.items())}
{'one': ['-', '-', 'a'], 'two': ['-', '-', 'b']}
```